# How to input,copy and paste into different file specific lines from millions in Emeditor?

Tags: excel, emeditor

What i am looking to achieve is simple, but i am a noob in this and i have tried to get that done.
I am used to copy in excel but in Emeditor i feel there is a better way of doing that, afterall it opens more file.

I do not want to be copying-down specific line range like i do in excel.

For instance, if i have a file that is 20million lines, and i need to copy only specific range, maybe between 1-2M or from 2M to 5M, without having to highlight and copydown, how do i go about it?

I will appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>F8</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to select whole lines) to mark the
   beginning point of a selection.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and specify the destination line number/column to jump to the ending  point.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the selection.